# close window in window overview

Tags: launcher, window-manager

I have several terminal windows open.
When I click on the terminal icon in the launcher, all terminal windows are shown in an overview.
Is it possible to close a windows from the overview without bringing every window to focus and close it manually.
It would be nice, if I could close a window in the overview by using the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no way to close windows from the overview.

I would look into putting in a feature request if you want this function added.

Comment: Would we still need to "put in a feature request" when this is already available in Gnome 3? It seems like it should be able to just be "turned on" somewhere.